# Proof that $\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi a}{a-b}\right) = \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi b}{a-b}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'd like to show that for all pairs of real numbers $a \neq b$,
$$\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  a}{a-b}\right) = \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  b}{a-b}\right).$$

When I put this into Mathematica, it fails to simplify it:

```
Sin[(2 a \[Pi])/(a - b)] - Sin[(2 b \[Pi])/(a - b)] // FullSimplify
```

It returns the input itself: `Sin[(2 a \[Pi])/(a - b)] - Sin[(2 b \[Pi])/(a - b)]`

However, if I use the fact that $$
\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  a}{a-b}\right) = \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  a(a+b)}{a^2-b^2}\right)=\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi a^2}{a^2-b^2}+\frac{2 \pi ab}{a^2-b^2}\right)
$$ followed by the angle sum formula, I get $0$, which is what I was hoping for:

```
expression1 = 
  Cos[(2 a b \[Pi])/(a^2 - b^2)] Sin[(2 a^2 \[Pi])/(a^2 - b^2)] + 
   Cos[(2 a^2 \[Pi])/(a^2 - b^2)] Sin[(2 a b \[Pi])/(a^2 - b^2)];
expression2 = 
  Cos[(2 b^2 \[Pi])/(a^2 - b^2)] Sin[(2 a b \[Pi])/(a^2 - b^2)] + 
   Cos[(2 a b \[Pi])/(a^2 - b^2)] Sin[(2 b^2 \[Pi])/(a^2 - b^2)];

expression1 - expression2 // FullSimplify

=> 0
```

Is there an easier way to see this identity?

Comment: You can also use that $\sin(A)-\sin(B)=2\cos(\frac{A+B}{2})\sin(\frac{A-B}{2})$.

Answer (score 4):

Since the $\sin$ function is $2\pi$-periodic, one has that:

\begin{align*}
\sin\left(\frac{2\pi a}{a -b}\right) & = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi a}{a - b} - 2\pi\right) = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi a + 2\pi(b - a)}{a - b}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi b}{a - b}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Now that I've posted the question, I see the answer isn't complicated: $\displaystyle\frac{2\pi a}{a-b}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{2\pi b}{a-b}$ differ by $2\pi$.

$$\frac{2\pi a}{a-b} - \frac{2\pi b}{a-b} = \frac{2\pi(a-b)}{a-b} = 2\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach:
\begin{align*}
\sin\left(\frac{2\pi a}{a - b}\right) & = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi(a - b + b)}{a - b}\right)\\\\
& = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi(a - b)}{a - b} + \frac{2\pi b}{a - b}\right)\\\\
& = \sin\left(2\pi + \frac{2\pi b}{a - b}\right)\\\\
& = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi b}{a - b}\right)
\end{align*}